# trigger search from select within jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

How do I trigger/call jQuery UI Autocomplete event handlers from each other, for example, triggering a search from the select handler?

Thx, Lille

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger a [search](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search):

```
$("#my-autocomplete").autocomplete("search", "SearchTerm");
```

In general, call jQueryUI widget methods using `$("selector").widget("method" /*, options */)`

Comment: OK, this works, but is it really the best approach to accessing the other events in the widget? I had been thinking some reference to the current instance of the widget -- already attached to the dom element -- would have been better. Something like the following pseudo: `this.trigger("search", "something here")`.

Comment: I think using the documented API is the best way to go here

Comment: or `$("#my-autocomplete").autocomplete("search", $("#my-autocomplete").val());`

Answer (score 7):

The answer above is only valid for jQueryUI **1.8.x**
Since jQueryUI **1.9.x** you must add a timeout:

> scott.gonzalez says:
>   "There were some pretty big changes to autocomplete between 1.8 and
>   1.9, specifically selection is now synchronous where before it was asynchronous."

more:

> scott.gonzalez says:
>   "What's happening is selecting an item always closes the menu. Closing
>   the menu tells the autocomplete to ignore any pending searches. This
>   includes the search that you're manually triggering immediately before
>   the menu closes. It's also worth noting that you're running a
>   duplicative search, since you're triggering the search before the
>   value updates."

```
select: function(event, ui)
{
    var that = $(this);            
    setTimeout(function() {
      that.autocomplete("search");
    }, 1);
},
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/RB4N3/