# jQUery UI - displaying autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jQuery Autocomplete for an input box. My "source" option contains very specific logic to fetch data and sort / filter it based on a criteria.

When the user selects a suggestion in the UI, based on the type of suggestion selected, I need to invoke the auto suggest once more.

As I understand from the [API](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search), I need to trigger the `search` event. How do I trigger that event (from within the `select` event) and on defining the event handler for `search` how do I invoke the auto suggest once again.

Basically, I know how to create an event handler for the `search` event but how do I trigger it from within the `select` event and inside the event handler how do I invoke the `source` to get the update values?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984151/trigger-search-from-select-within-jquery-ui-autocomplete)

To call from within select:

```
$("#my-autocomplete").autocomplete("search", "SearchTerm");
```

I do not need to explicitly handle the `search` event and my `source` function is automatically triggered.