# JQuery autocomplete trigger search

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

If it pleases you to assist me with the inquire below I would greatly appreciate it.

I have a search field (#sidebar-search). Search may be entered manually or via barcode scanner.
A barcode scan is captured but I need it to also trigger a search. $( "#sidebar-search input:text" ).search()  or $("#sidebar-search input:text").trigger( "change" ); don't seem to work.

Below is the top section of my code.

```
 $(function() {

   $('body').keydown(function(ev) {
      if(ev.which == 192) { // Backtick `
         ev.preventDefault();
         $("#sidebar-search input:text").val('').focus();
       }
   });

**$("#sidebar-search input:text").on("change", function(val){
    $("#sidebar-search input:text").autocomplete("search", $("#sidebar-search 
    input:text").val());
});**

$( "#sidebar-search input:text" ).autocomplete({
minLength: 2,
select: function(event, ui) {
    //ui.type to drive redir
    window.location.href = paths.frontend_search + '?term=' + ui.item.value;
},
source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: paths.api_v1_search,
      data: {
        term: request.term
      }}).always(app.always(function(o) {
          if(o.success) {
              response(o.results);
          }
      }));
  },
});
```

I've added the lines marked with ** and that solves my issue.

Comment: you should look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12984151/trigger-search-from-select-within-jquery-ui-autocomplete

Comment: JQueryUI Autocomplete has its own methods to trigger searches. Look at their documentation at https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-search

Comment: I have tried: $("#sidebar-search input:text").autocomplete("search", $("#sidebar-search input:text").val());  but for some reason (maybe the preventDefault()?) the search does not get triggered.